# Description linebreaks on YouTube v3 API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've been playing around with the YouTube API but when I try to get the video description, it appears as one long string with no line breaks. Is there a method to get line breaks?

The API does not have any documentation to explain this matter.

Comment: APIs return data its up to the developer to format it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When uploading a video using the API, I set .Snippet.Description, my data contains CrLf characters to cause line breaks. Later, when I retrieve the Video object via the API, the line breaks are present.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the PHP_EOL, like so:

```
$desp='Cette vidéo et trouvée sur: http://localhost/ '.PHP_EOL;
$desp.='Pour plus d\'infos visitez: http://localhost/123 '.PHP_EOL;
$desp.='CopyRight to: http://localhost/789';
$snippet->setDescription($desp);
```